# Breaking a chess coordinate string into 2D coordinates

Tags: ruby, game, array, coordinate-system

Given a chess coordinate as a string (e.g. "a1") I'd like to transform it into a 2-D array (so, for "a1" I'd like to get [1,1]).

Here's what I came up with:

```
def safe_pawns(pawns)
  pawns.inject([]){|res, pwn| res << [pwn.split('')[0].index(/[a-h]/) + 1, pwn.split('')[1].to_i]}
end
```

Can anyone suggest a refactoring please to make it more idiomatic Ruby?

Comment: out of curiosity, why not [0,0] for "a1" ?

Comment: Purely out of habit. I learned ROT13 way before I learned of coding. :) I can see why you ask: why have a "+1" in the mapping of the letter character into the array... and you are absolutely right! Like I said, force of habit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Give your code some breathing room. I.e. `) { |a, b|` instead of `){|a, b|`. And there's no need to put everything on one line. The way your block works right now, it'd be better to store the result of `pwn.split` in a variable, instead of calling `split` twice. (There's also no need to abbrevate "pawn" as "pwn".)
2. That being said, strings support array-like access, so you don't need the `split` at all.
3. Judging from your code, `pawns` is an array. Transforming an *n*-element array to a new *n*-element array is called "mapping". You're using `inject` which is also known as `reduce` (and `fold` in many other languages; see comments) - an operation most often used to take an *n*-element array and reduce it to a single value. So step 1: Use `map` instead of `inject`.
4. I'd probably use a regex to pull the string apart. It'll double as a way to check the coordinate strings for validity (e.g. so no "z9" coordinates will slip through).
5. It's a little low-level, but we can use the fact that "a" is 97 in ASCII. So to get the number for a letter, we can say `letter.ord - 96`.

You get something like this:

```
def safe_pawns(squares)
  squares.map do |square|
    [$1.ord - 96, $2.to_i] if square.downcase =~ /^([a-h])([1-8])$/
  end.compact
end
```

Alternatively, if you're sure that all the input coordinates are valid, lowercase strings already, you don't need the regex or the downcasing:

```
def safe_pawns(squares)
  squares.map { |square| [square[0].ord - 96, square[1].to_i] }
end
```

As tokland points out in the comments, we can avoid the hardcoded `96` (which isn't very self-explanatory) and instead get the letter-to-number translation by saying:

```
square[0].ord - 'a'.ord + 1
```

Comment: Wow! Lots of ***helpful*** tips ("teach a man to fish") an their final accumulation ("give them a fish"). Not to mention a non-textbook, one-liner explanation on what `inject` is.  Thank you very, very much. Can't upvote yet 'cause I don't have enough cred, but this sure is the _accepted answer_ by me.

Comment: Note that in "reducing to a single value", the "single value" can be arbitrarily complex … like another array, for example. In fact, `reduce` is *universal*: *everything* you can do with iteration aka `each` (and that means everything you can do with *any* of the methods in `Enumerable`), you can do with `reduce`. There is a [proof sketch on the Wikipedia page for `fold`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Universality), and as a proof-of-concept I once [re-implemented much of `Enumerable` on top of `reduce` instead of `each`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3834035/2988).

Comment: It becomes much clearer if you stop thinking of `reduce` as "iterating" and the first argument as an "accumulator" or "starting value". Instead think of it like this: when going through a collection there is either a next element or there isn't. `reduce` takes two arguments, telling it what to when there is a next element (the block) and there isn't (the zero). Therefore, we have covered all possible cases.

Comment: Another possible way is to think of it as an interpreter: a collection is a program with two kinds of commands, a stop command and a parametric `do` command. `reduce` interprets that program, and it allows *you* to specify how to interpret the stop command (the zero) and the `do` command (the block). Note that the opposite is also true, by the way: a compiler or interpreter is really just a `reduce` of an abstract syntax tree!

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, following your proof-of-concept I've seen you called `reduce`\`inject` by the name `fold`. I hate to admit I didn't see the connection before, but I know `fold` from some Mathematica stuff I used way back. It all makes perfect sense now. All these names that each help understand that method's behavior from a different perspective. Thank you for your detailed comments and the links.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Note that I did say that reduce/fold/inject is _most often used_ to reduce to a single value :)  Or at any rate used to, well, reduce the complexity of some data (i.e. doing sums, products, etc.). But you're perfectly right of course; it doesn't have to be used that way. Thanks for adding all the additional explanation.

Comment: Two minor notes: 1) In chess the coordinates are called "squares". 2) To avoid "magic numbers" I'd write: `square[1].ord - 'a'.ord  + 1`.

Comment: @tokland Good points - I'll note that in my answer